# How do I get the URL of opened tabs in google chrome browser

Tags: c#, windows-services

I export my project to services and I can get all my processes, I get the "chrome" processes but I dunno how to get the url of tabs,
here is the start

```
//start 
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        LogText("MMA_Service", "In OnStart.");
        System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        timer.Interval = 60000; // 60 seconds
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(this.OnTimer);
        timer.Start();
        ServiceStatus serviceStatus = new ServiceStatus();
        serviceStatus.dwCurrentState = ServiceState.SERVICE_START_PENDING;
        serviceStatus.dwWaitHint = 100000;
        SetServiceStatus(this.ServiceHandle, ref serviceStatus);
        serviceStatus.dwCurrentState = ServiceState.SERVICE_RUNNING;
        SetServiceStatus(this.ServiceHandle, ref serviceStatus);
     }
```

here is the ontimer method

```
    //onTimer
       public void OnTimer(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs args)
    {
        LogText("MMA_Service", "Monitoring the System " + (eventId++).ToString());
        IntPtr CHandle = GetChromeHandle();

    }
```

and here I want to het the url of the process

```
    // GetChromeProcess
     public static IntPtr GetChromeHandle()
    {

    Process[] Allpro = Process.GetProcesses();
    foreach (Process pro in Allpro)
    {
        if (pro.ProcessName == "chrome")
        {
                //get the url !!
        }
    }
    }
```